# MCB with electronic trigger-off

Tags: relay, power-electronics, circuit-breaker

How can I design a system that gives the functionality of an MCB (overload protection, operates in an AC circuit) with an electronic trigger-off.

So that once the device is in ON state, it should be able to be turned-off by

1. Human interaction (mechanically flipping the latch)
2. Over-load (MCB inherent feature)
3. Electronically, by using a small trigger voltage. Once this trigger is applied this switch should be mechanically flipped to off position, so that the user should see it is in OFF state.

The device is to be used to run a domestic motor (say 1HP.)

Comment: It sounds like you want to purchase a device for this purpose. This site is specifically for the **design** of electronic circuits, so we don't like to recommend specific products. Such recommendations rarely have lasting value, and we want to avoid any product promotion as well.

Comment: Did you not search for "Remotely Operated Circuit Breakers"? There's plenty of results.

Comment: In molded case circuit breakers, there are shunt-trip breakers that are tripped by energizing a solenoid inside the circuit breaker. They may also have other names. That feature may not me available in miniature circuit breakers.

Comment: Shunt trips are routinely available for most industrial/commercial DIN rail mount product families. They clip on the side. For SE Acti9, this is an iMX. For ABB S200, this is an S2CA*. Both are available with different coil voltages. Domestic-grade breakers usually don't have these accessories available.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f48lTb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. RCD/ELCB/GFCI and relay.*

> 1. Human interaction (mechanically flipping the latch)

Toggle the RCD switch.

> 2. Over-load (MCB inherent feature)

Built in on the RCD.

> 3.Electronically, by using a small trigger voltage. Once this trigger is applied this switch should be mechanically flipped to off position, so that the user should see it is in OFF state.

- Use a relay to switch in a resistance to unbalance the RCD/ELCB/GFCI<sup>1</sup>.
- When R1 and R2 are switched in there will be more current passing through the live pole of the RCD than is returning on the neutral pole.
- On 230 V systems 4.4 kΩ will result in 50 mA difference and this should trip a 30 mA RCD. On 120 V systems R2 may be omitted.

> The device is to be used to run a domestic motor (say 1 HP).

You omitted the voltage so we don't know what current this is likely to be so you'll need to work that out.

---

- RCD = residual current device.
- ELCB = earth leakage circuit breaker.
- GFCI = ground-fault circuit interrupter.

They're all pretty much the same.

Comment: The house may be protected by another RCD, which means this system will sitting inside another RCD. While we imbalance the RCD will the main RCB also get triggered.

Comment: That could be a problem. In some countries only the power sockets are on RCD so that the house lights, etc., remain on in the event of a trip. (No point in saving someone's life with an RCD and then kill them falling down the stairs going to the fuse box in the dark.) Check your installation to see. I offered the solution as a novel way of achieving your requirements.